# Duplicity no longer works with Amazon S3

Tags: duplicity

Duplicity 0.6.10 doesnt seem to like the `s3+http` protocol. I keep getting the following error message.

```
unsupportedbackendscheme: scheme not supported in url: s3+http://<bucketname>
```

I've tried with 0.6.09 as well and no luck. I finally got down to 0.6.06 and was able to finally backup my system. Did I miss something? Changelog doesn't show any changes to the S3 protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Working on it...

As to Python 2.3, the only place it's mentioned is setup.py -- I just committed a fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. I've submitted a [question ticket](https://answers.launchpad.net/duplicity/+question/128051) to the developers.

**Update**

The bug has been fixed by Duplicity developers. 
A [patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/655468/+attachment/1675322/+files/botobackend.py.diff) against for the problem is now available.

Details: See the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/655468)

Comment: Yea I came across your ticket via google search. I've opened a separate ticket before regarding a different issue and it went unanswered. I may start looking at alternatives if I can't get help when I run into problems.

Comment: @luckytaxi: We'll see. I remain hopeful--I only submitted the question last night. Based on your report I also submitted a bug report to them. Duplicity has a good rep. Thanks for the idea of downgrading, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Me too. Duplicity refuses to work with python 2.3 and upgrading to 2.4 is out of te question. I've resorted to rdiff-backup on my  rhel 4 boxes.

Comment: now im getting. `BackendException: Boto requires a bucket name.`

Comment: I created my bucket explicitly using the Amazon aws tool: http://timkay.com/aws/ Then I used duplicity. Also, are you using the 
damontimm script? See http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-automated-secure-encrypted-incremental-backups-amazon-s3-duplicity-os-x-or-ubuntu/